# File Upload Across Sub Domains

Tags: laravel, file-upload

I have two **subdomains**; **admin.example.com** and **app.example.com**.  When a user uploads an image from admin.example.com I don't want the folder to reside in that sub domain's home directory but rather a central uploads folder possibly in my main public_html folder that all my subdomains can access.

I know this is about file permissions and what not but I'm not too sure how to go about it or if it is even possible.

Comment: What about creating a new disk into the filesystem config file that points to your required directory? Would that make sense in your case?

Comment: Unfortunately I do not understand what you mean.

Comment: What I'm suggesting is that you configure different [local disk drivers](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/filesystem) in your `config/filesystems.php` file to send your upload to. You can configure it to point to whatever folder you want.

Comment: I don't seem to be able to point it to a folder outside the sub domains root folder though. I get 500 internal server error.

Comment: That might be a limitation of your host?